# Grails render view is not rendering and not giving any error

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-2.0

I am using Grails grails-2.5.6 version. I am trying to render a view not template from the controller during an ajax call. But failing. It shows no error at all and stay on the current page. It call the controller action also.

Here is my code. My AJAX call:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dashboard-item", function(e) {
        var $element = $(this);
        var controller = $element.attr("controller"),
            action = $element.attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: CONTEXT_PATH + '/' + controller + '/' + action,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: 9999,
                value: "val9999"
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $.blockUI({
                        css: {
                            border: 'none',
                            padding: '5px',
                            'background-color': 'transparent',
                            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                            '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                            opacity: .8,
                            color: '#fff',
                            cursor: 'default'
                        },
                message: '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="font-size:40px;"></i> &nbsp; ' +
                '<span class="ajax-wait-message">Please Wait while Loading ...</span>'
            });
            },
            success: function (response) {

                $.unblockUI();
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $(".alert-danger").removeClass("hidden").find('.dng-span').text(errorThrown);
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    });
```

My controller render:

```
def testA1() {
    render(view: 'test1')
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Does the view 'test1' exist in the folder that is named the same as your controller? Does testA1 endpoint execute during request?

Comment: yes, it does fully

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the success part as follows >>

```
success: function (response) {
                document.open();
                document.write(response);
                document.close();

                $.unblockUI();
            }
```